# SharePoint calculated fields - get the first date from 4 columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-fields

I need a little bit of help with calculated fields in SharePoint. I have 4 dates (it can be more in the future). All 4 dates are **due** dates. So lets say I have 4 fields.

[Car Damage repair]
[Car cleaning]
[Car Polishing]
[Car Maintenance]

Now I want a calculated field [Planning first date] which gives me the closest date from now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create 3 Calculated fields to realize your design.

**Please follow steps:**

1.Create the first Calculated field named "C1"

**Formula:**

```
=IF(INT([Car Damage repair])>INT([Car cleaning]),[Car Damage repair],[Car cleaning])
//compare the values of the first two fields
```

[image]

2.Create the second Calculated field named "C2"

**Formula:**

```
=IF(INT([Car Polishing])>INT([Car Maintenance]),[Car Polishing],[Car Maintenance])
//compare the values of the last two fields
```

[image]

3.Create the last Calculated field named "Closest date"

**Formula:**

```
=IF(INT(C1)>INT(C2),C1,C2)
//compare the values of [C1] and  [C2]
```

[image]

4.Go to List page, click the column field **[C1]** and select **Column settings** >> **Hide this column**. **[C2]** is the same operation.

[image]

[image]